# Django URLs with/without proxy server

Tags: django, proxy-server, urlconf

I have two Django apps (say, `app1` and `app2`) hosted on the same machine using Apache mod_wsgi. These two apps are hosted on two different environments:

1. On a physical server where only these two apps are hosted. They are accessed as `http://www.example.com/app1/app1/` and `http://www.example.com/app2/app2/`.
2. In the second environment there is a proxy server. A separate web page on that server is accessed as `http://www.domain.com/`. This links to the above two apps (now hosted on a single virtual machine) as `http://www.domain.com/id1/` and `http://www.domain.com/id2/`

The URLconf file looks like:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    (r'^app1/', include('project.app1.urls')),        
)
```

The problem is, this URL configurations works in the environment `1`, but not in the environment `2`. Now, if I do something *crazy* in the environment `2` such as

```
 urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    (r'^app1/app1/app1/', include('project.app1.urls')),        
    (r'^app1/app1/', include('project.app1.urls')),        
    (r'^app1/', include('project.app1.urls')),        
 )
```

then the application works. In the env. `2`, the app is accessed as `http://www.domain.com/id1/app1/app1/`.

I couldn't understand why we need to prefix `app1` in the URL so many times. In other words, why (how) this works.

Could someone clarify on this? Also, note that all configurations need to be done on the virtual machine. I don't have access to the proxy server.